# Terraform crash error while running terraform import on IBM cloud

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+, terraform-provider-ibm

I am trying to import ibm-cos-bucket and cos-instance from IBM cloud. I am able to import cos-instance however, getting error while importing ibm-cos-bucket.

**Error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing**

*[ERROR] : eval: *terraform.EvalRefresh, err: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
[ERROR] : eval: *terraform.EvalSequence, err: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
[WARN]  plugin.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing"
[DEBUG] plugin: plugin exited
panic: runtime error: index out of range [1] with length 1*

**Terraform crashed!!!**

here is sample resource block:-
`resource "ibm_cos_bucket" "mybucket" {}`

Please help me in this regards.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did it go? Did you manage to make an issue on github?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using CRN or ID for import?

According to [doc's](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs/resources/cos_bucket#import) ID must be used.

id = $CRN:meta:$buckettype:$bucketlocation

ID can be easily find by using data. Here is an example.

```
data "ibm_cos_bucket" "my-bucket" {
  bucket_name = "my-bucket"
  resource_instance_id = data.ibm_resource_instance.my-resource.id
  bucket_region = "us-south"
  bucket_type = "region_location"
}

output "bucket-info" {
  value = data.ibm_cos_bucket.my-bucket.id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a **fault/bug of IBM provider**. Simillar issue for aws is [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/16073).

Thus, you can report the problem by making the issue on IBM provider's github:

- https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/terraform-provider-ibm/issues